# Printing too many numbers with queue, pipe and scanf

Tags: c, linux

I have problem with fscanf, when I'm reading numbers from my txt file i read all of them and  print them (15 numbers in one line) and then program keep printing last number in txt file. Any ideas how can I solve this?

I have to get numbers from txt file in process #1 then send it with queue to process #2, in process #2 change type to hex and send with pipe to process #3, where I print all data.

//edit My example input "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16"

i expect "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F

10"

but i get "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

struct mymsgbuf {
    long    mtype;         
    int     request;       
    int     i;
} send;

int pid, pid1, pid2, pid3, qid, k=0; 
int wybor;
FILE * plik;
struct mymsgbuf recv;

int open_queue( key_t keyval ) 
{
    int     qid;          
    if((qid = msgget( keyval, IPC_CREAT | 0660 )) == -1) return(-1);       
    return(qid);
}

int send_message( int qid, struct mymsgbuf *qbuf )
{
    int result, length;
    length = sizeof(struct mymsgbuf) - sizeof(long);        
    if((result = msgsnd( qid, qbuf, length, 0)) == -1)  return(-1); 
    return(result);
}

int remove_queue( int qid )
{
    if( msgctl( qid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) return(-1);
    return(0);
}

int read_message( int qid, long type, struct mymsgbuf *qbuf )
{
    int     result, length;
    length = sizeof(struct mymsgbuf) - sizeof(long);        
    if((result = msgrcv( qid, qbuf, length, type,  0)) == -1) return(-1);
    return(result);
}

void obsluga(int sig)
{
    remove_queue(qid);
    fclose(plik);
    kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
}

int main(void)
{
    pid=getpid();
    printf("1. Type numbers\n");
    printf("2. Read from file\n");
    printf("3. Read from /dev/urandom\n");
    scanf("%d", &wybor);
    plik = fopen("dane.txt","r");
    int dana=114;
    char hex[256];
    char odbior[256];
    int pdes[2];
    pipe(pdes);
    key_t msgkey;
    msgkey = ftok(".", 'm');
    if(( qid = open_queue( msgkey)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("Otwieranie_kolejki");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fork()==0)
    {
        printf("Proces 1: %d\n", getpid());

        pid1=getpid();
        send.request = 1;
        for(;;)
        {
            if(wybor==1)
            {
                scanf("%d", &dana);

            }
            if(wybor==2) //read from file
            {
                 fscanf(plik, "%d", &dana);
            }
            send.i = dana;
            send.mtype = 2;
            if((send_message( qid, &send )) == -1) //send with queue
            {
                perror("Wysylanie");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    if (fork()==0)
    {   
        printf("Proces 2: %d\n", getpid());
        pid2=getpid();  
        close(pdes[0]);
        recv.mtype = 2;
        recv.request = 1;
        for(;;)
        {
            //read from queue and change type to hex
            read_message(qid, recv.mtype, &recv);   
            sprintf(hex, "%X", recv.i);
            //write to pipe
            write(pdes[1], hex, sizeof(hex));
        }   
    }   
    if (fork()==0)
    {
        printf("Proces 3: %d\n", getpid());
        pid3=getpid();
        close(pdes[1]);
        for(;;)
        {   
            //read from pipe and print
            read(pdes[0], odbior, sizeof(odbior));          
            if(wybor==2)
            {           
                if(k<14)
                {
                    printf("%s ", odbior);  
                    k++;
                }
                else
                {   
                    printf("%s ", odbior);  
                    printf("\n");
                    k=0;
                    sleep(1);
                }
            }
            else printf("\n %s \n", odbior);
        }
    }
    for(;;)
    {
        signal(SIGINT, obsluga);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us some example input, and the expected output *plus* the actual output.

Comment: Well one problem is that you have infinite loops in your child processes. And you don't check for end of the file, or the closing of the queue or pipe.

Comment: I was trying to check for EOF but it was still printing last number Forever

Comment: You check for `EOF` by checking what [the `scanf` or `fscanf` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) return. And it goes on forever since you have infinite loops.

Comment: So how should I write it to check for EOF and if it's EOF stop all process. I tried if(fscanf(plik, "%d", &dana)==EOF) kill(parentpid, SIGKILL); but it didnt work

Comment: When you reach the end of the file, simply "close" the message queue and exit. Then the next process in the chain will notice that (if you add a check for it), clean up and close the pipe and exit. Which will then propagate to the next process which does the same. The parent process isn't actually needed, it can exit once it has created the three child threads.

Comment: Check return value of `fscanf(plik, "%d", &dana);`.

Comment: In the main thread, you are busy looping and calling `signal()` repeatedly. This is quite bad. You only need to call `signal()` once. Instead of a busy loop, use `wait()` to suspend the thread until one of its children dies.